# How to get Seq of elements which were grouped in GROUP BY clause?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have three case classes:

```
case class Section(key: Key, from: String, to: String, travellers: Int)

case class Course(groupedSections: Seq[GroupedSection])

case class GroupedSection(from: String, to: String, sections: Seq[Section])
```

The sections aren't unique e.g.

```
(Section(key1, "a", "b", 1), Section(key1, "a", "b", 2), Section(key1, "b", "c", 3), Section(key2, "a", "b", 1))
```

and I want to get courses which contain groupedSections by the key which would look like this in my example:

```
(Course(
    GroupedSection("a", "b", (section1, section2 (I shortened this))), GroupedSection("b", "c", (section3))), 
 Course(
    GroupedSection("a", "b", (section4)))
)
```

The sections Seq is important, so that I can get different attributes of the Section class in a further step. My question is, if it's possible to add all Sections which were group in a Seq inside the GroupedSection class via spark. I tried something like this, but I know no way to get a Seq of the Sections:

```
sections
      .groupBy("key")
      .agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct("from", "to"))).as(
        "groupedSections"))
      .select($"groupedSections")
      .as[Course]
```

If you need more information, just let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you exactly want to do is perform a groupBy on an array that was get by using `collect_list` during a groupBy on a dataframe.

As from spark 3.0.1, there is no [built-in functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) that can group an array by a key. Given that, you have two choices:

- You can use only Spark built-in functions and then you should perform two groupBy on your dataframe.
- As you already have case classes, you can transform your dataframe to dataset, group by your key and perform the groupBy on your array using scala code

### Solution with only Spark built-in functions

In this case, you perform two groupBy. The first one using "key", "from" and "to" columns and the second one using only "key" column. The first create the list of sections that will be used by the second groupBy to create the courses:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_list, struct}

import sparkSession.implicits._

sections
  .groupBy("key", "from", "to").agg(
    collect_list(
      struct(col("key"), col("from"), col("to"), col("travellers"))
    ).as("sections")
  )
  .groupBy("key").agg(collect_list(
     struct(col("from"), col("to"), col("sections"))
  ).as("groupedSections"))
  .select("groupedSections")
  .as[Course]
```

#### Solution with datasets

Here you cast your dataframe's rows to `Section`, use method [groupByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#groupByKey%5BK%5D(func:T=%3EK)(implicitevidence$3:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BK%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.KeyValueGroupedDataset%5BK,T%5D) to group by your key and then perform your transformation to `Course` using [mapGroups](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html#mapGroups%5BU%5D(f:(K,Iterator%5BV%5D)=%3EU)(implicitevidence$4:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D) method:

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._

sections
  .as[Section]
  .groupByKey(_.key)
  .mapGroups((_, sections) => Course(
    sections.toSeq
      .groupBy(s => (s.from, s.to))
      .map(keyValue => GroupedSection(keyValue._1._1, keyValue._1._2, keyValue._2))
      .toSeq
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the the solution with Spark built-in functions and it worked for me.